# why am I not able to get this to display

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this reminder app which allows you to have a name for it, a date and some extra information. I am able to get it to store locally but I can't get it to display. Can I get some help to get it to display?

```js
let reminders = [];

const addReminders = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  let reminder = {
    ReminderInput: document.getElementById("ReminderInput").value,
    DateInput: document.getElementById("DateInput").value,
    InfoInput: document.getElementById("InfoInput").value,
  };

  const arr = [reminder.ReminderInput, reminder.DateInput, reminder.InfoInput];

  localStorage.setItem("todoForm", JSON.stringify(arr));
  reminders.push([
    reminder.ReminderInput,
    reminder.DateInput,
    reminder.InfoInput,
  ]);
  localStorage.setItem("reminders", JSON.stringify(reminders));
  localStorage.getItem("reminders", JSON.parse(reminders));
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {  
  document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", addReminders);
});
```

```html
<form id="todoForm">
  <label for="ReminderInput">Reminder</label>
  <input class="u-full-width" type="text" id="ReminderInput">

  <label for="DateInput">Date</label>
  <input class="u-full-width" type="datetime-local" id="DateInput">

  <label for="InfoInput">Additional Information</label>
  <textarea class="u-full-width" type="text" placeholder="Remember to..." id="InfoInput"></textarea>
  <button type="button" id="btn" class="button-primary">Add Reminder</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `getItem()` only takes one argument, and you need to assign the result somewhere.

Comment: I don't see any code that tries to display the reminder. Where is it supposed to appear?

Comment: Where are you trying to display it? I don't see anything

Comment: You'll need to write some code to display it. Right now you're only using a form in HTML for the user to input the information.

I belive you should be looking at some templating like EJS to give it a start.

Also, like @Barmar said, you need to assign the result of your `getItem()` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

change this line `localStorage.getItem("reminders", JSON.parse(reminders));` with `var reminderData=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("reminders"));`

`localStorage.getItem("reminders")` is the correct way to fetch localstorage data

Comment: Don't put text in the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```
`     
    let reminders = [];    
    const addReminders = (ev) => {
      ev.preventDefault();
      let reminder = {
        ReminderInput: document.getElementById("ReminderInput").value,
        DateInput: document.getElementById("DateInput").value,
        InfoInput: document.getElementById("InfoInput").value,
      };

      const arr = [reminder.ReminderInput, reminder.DateInput, 
 reminder.InfoInput];

      localStorage.setItem("todoForm", JSON.stringify(arr));
      reminders.push([
        reminder.ReminderInput,
        reminder.DateInput,
        reminder.InfoInput,
      ]);
      localStorage.setItem("reminders", JSON.stringify(reminders));
      display();
    };

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {  
      document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", addReminders);

    });

    function display()
    {
        var reminderData =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("reminders"));
        alert(reminderData);
        for(let i = 0; i < reminderData.length;i++)
        {
            alert(reminderData[i][0]);
            alert(reminderData[i][1]);
            alert(reminderData[i][2]);
        }
    }
` 

//you can use the getItem operation.

//you would have to 
//1. get item
//2. parse it (from string to array)
//3. iterate over and display

//above is the javascript. change date-time to date...then you can add in 
//the values however you like to an empty div. call display when the browser 
//loads as well
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display your data firstly you have to mention where you want display your data. if you want to just test that value is coming so just use this:

```
var data = localStorage.getItem("reminders");
alert(data);
```

OR

```
console.log(data);
```